# Visual Studio 2019 Xamarin - Error starting Android Emulator

Tags: xamarin, emulation

rror:
WARNING: unexpected '-prop' value ('monodroid.avdname=pixel_2_q_10_0_-_api_29'), only 'qemu.' properties are supported
WARNING: unexpected '-prop' value ('emu.uuid=247e01dd-5fb3-47fe-92ec-b73d9583cfe3'), only 'qemu.' properties are supported

Description:
When I click on the Run button in the Android Device Manager - the error appears immediately[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTMjP.png)

Comment: please do not post duplicate questions.  Did you look at the comment I posted on your first question?

Comment: didn't work for me